# Proper Style for this SQL

Tags: sql, coding-style

what is the proper new line and indentation for this sql code?

```
sql = "select p.diff, away_score - home_score, clock from 
     (select possession,away_score,home_score, play_type, clock, 
               (lag(clock, 1) over (order by id) - clock) as diff 
               from plays where game_id in #{ids}
               and league = 1 offset 1) 
       as p 
       where possession= 0 and 
       play_type not in (150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 105, 106)
       and diff > 0 and diff < 30;"
```

Comment: Do you want the "sql=" included? Or do you want just the SQL statement formatted as tsql?

Comment: wouldn't they be similar? i prefer with the "sql = "

Comment: In the past I used an [SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm). It is very handy. When I run your code with the "sql=", the format stays the same. That formatter has a lot of options you can set too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no right answer to this question. Style, formatting, whitespace, all are by and large personal preferences. SQL won't much care if it was all a single line (note that this is based on my experiences with MS SQL Server, other systems might be a bit fussier). If N people viewed *and* replied to this question, you would get N answers, and N(N-1) dissenting opinions.

With that said, here's how I'd do it:

```
sql = "
select
   p.diff
  ,away_score - home_score
  ,clock
 from (--  Comment describing the subquery
       select
          possession
         ,away_score
         ,home_score
         ,play_type
         ,clock
         ,(lag(clock, 1) over (order by id) - clock) as diff 
        from plays
        where game_id in #{ids}
         and league = 1 offset 1
      ) as p 
  where possession = 0
   and play_type not in (150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 105, 106)
   and diff > 0
   and diff < 30;
"
```

Comment: why do you prefer to put the commas at the beginning of a line before a word and not in the typical fashion of at the end of a line after a word?

Comment: Main reason: over the years, time and again I found I forgot to add that critical comma, and it took far too long to figure out why the code failed and where the comma got missed. This way it's easy to remember and pretty obvious when missed.

Comment: Other reason: some times that lack of comma is important, it shows where a chunk of code was so long it got spread over multiple lines. Don't see the comma? It's a run-on bit of syntax.

Comment: Minor and more subtle reason: when testing/debugging code, if some columns need to be dropped or commented out, figuring out where to add/remove commas is quicker if they're all lined up that way.